# How to display certain logs from 3rd parties during Gradle build

Tags: logging, gradle, build.gradle

My application uses Gradle 3.5. On the beginning of the build, I execute my own `library` which uses log4j to log messages.

What I need is to display INFO messages during `gradle build` which my `library` produces.

E.g. to get output like this one:

```
[INFO ] [com.mylibrary] A message 1
[ERROR] [com.mylibrary] A message 1
[INFO ] [com.mylibrary] A message 2
:compileJava
:compileGroovy
... etc.
```

I do not want to run `gradle --info` as the console is then flooded by way too much crap I do not want to disturb the users with.

Is there a way to accomplish that? The [Gradle Logging doc](https://docs.gradle.org/3.5/userguide/logging.html) talks only about stdout redirecting to a different error level.

Also, is there a way to change the output pattern I would normally do by specifying `ConversionPattern` in `log4j`?

Comment: How is your library called in `build.gradle` ?

Comment: Is the name important? :) It's using a pattern `com.company.product:company-upgrade-code:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`. I did specify it as dependency, and in a Gradle task I do run the library's `new Upgrade().execute()` method which internally logs using log4j.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle uses its own implementations of `slf4j` and `log4j`. There is no way to override any settings, except using `--info` or `--debug` command line argument.

To be able to print out logs my library generates, I have defined a new Gradle task of `JavaExec` type and this way Gradle's own logging implementations are avoided, and my library uses correct logger defined in its dependencies.